# Facebook Canvas url using routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, redirect, routes, facebook-canvas

I'd like my FB canvas app

```
apps.facebook.com/coolapp
```

to behave the same as my web app

```
coolapp.com
```

I've set up the canvas url in facebook developer page

```
http://coolapp.com/canvas/
```

Using Rails 3.1, I'd like to know how I can easily route the /canvas into my app so that going to the first url above does not route outside of the facebook canvas page (and all the resources work as expected).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18028579/156561 i link to how to do all this (2 yrs later) in this question.

Comment: @pjammer - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: yeah man, will do tonight. thanks for not just bogarting it like so many of the other leeches here :-) kidding you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> [stackoverflow.com/a/18028579/156561](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18028579/156561) i link to how to do all this (2 yrs later) in this question.

~ answer per [pjammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156561/pjammer)